# Change figure position by mouse

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I plotted two curves as shown in the following figure. I want to match the subplot curve (ax1) with one of the main curves by changing the position of the ax1 with the mouse in the X and Y direction. How i can do that?

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xl = pd.ExcelFile('Book2.xlsx')
column = xl.parse('Sheet1', names=['A', 'B', 'C'], header=None, index_col=False)

time = np.array(column['A'])
rate = np.array(column['B'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

tDd = np.arange(10e-4, 10e2, 1)

plt.plot()
b = np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)
index = 0
for i in tDd:
    q_Dd = [np.exp(-tDd) if b == 0 else (1+b*tDd)**(-1/b) for b in b]
    ax.loglog(tDd,q_Dd[index], 'b-')
    if index <= 8: index += 1 
    
plt.xlim(10e-4, 10e1)
plt.ylim(10e-4, 10e0)

ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5])
ax1.patch.set_alpha(0.5)
ax1.loglog(time,rate,'.')
```

Comment: Maybe the pylustrator package is able to do this (this is not a safe call).

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much.